# How to visualise timing trace data?

Tags: optimization, visualization, data-visualization, timing, trace

I am writing some software which does a few different tasks repeatedly, and I can produce a trace from this of interval timing data (also queue depth data is of interest).

I'm looking for good ways to visualise this data so I can see at a glance, for example, what the timing jitter looks like, and outliers (occasional extremely slowly handled events) to help me tune performance.

I've played around with gnuplot for live viewing under X11, which is *okay*, and in the past I've produced CSV files and imported them into MS Excel to draw some graphs.

I'm wondering if there's some nice software out there for this kind of thing. I'm interested in producing static graph images, but I'm more interested in some kind of live viewer GUI that supports independent horizontal and vertical zooming.

The trace data is produced with my code which I can change, and I preprocess with a Perl script after a test run, so I can output pretty much any format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html

Is the easiest to pick up through its google spreadsheet interface

A new tool that makes Time-Series dashboarding easy is Cube: http://square.github.com/cube/

Another simple and beautiful JavaScript library for time-series is: http://dygraphs.com/

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. dygraphs.com looks particularly interesting, my web dev skills are basic and rusty but I hope to give that one a go.

The google one is interesting but I prefer something self-contained that doesn't require an internet connection (correct me if I'm wrong).